# Disable clicking through other controls - WPF

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, events, button

I have Simple application.

---

[image]

---

```
<Window x:Class="WpfControlReview.MainWindow" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" Title="MainWindow" mc:Ignorable="d" xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" Height="120" Width="277" ResizeMode="NoResize">
    <Grid>
        <Button HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Name="button1" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" Click="button1_Click">
        <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Name="stackPanel1" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Orientation="Vertical">
            <Label IsHitTestVisible="False" Content="Select your options and press to commit" Name="label1" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" FontSize="12" />
            <StackPanel Name="stackPanel2" Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Expander Header="Color" x:Name="expander1"/>
                <Expander Header="Make" x:Name="expander2"/>
                <Expander Header="Payment" x:Name="expander3"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </StackPanel>
        </Button>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

---

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e)
{
 Application.Current.Shutdown();
}
```

When I click button application closes. That is what I want.
But when I click on one of the expanders application also closes. How to avoid that? I don't want application to close when user clicks on one of three arrows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try checking the source for the click (as Click events bubble up until someone explicitly handles them). And because the Button is a parent of the expander, it will receive its click event too (did you mean to put the expander **outside** the button?):

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  if (e.Source == this.button1)
  {
    Application.Current.Shutdown();
  }
}
```

Comment: I want expanderto be inside. Button is parent